# Geometric intuition for Mather's cube theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, intuition

Mather's cube theorem for the category of topological spaces says that given a homotopy-commutative cube:

> If one pair of opposite faces are homotopy pushouts and the two
>   remaining faces adjecent the source vertex are homotopy pullbacks,
>   then the final two faces are also homotopy pullbacks.

What is the geometric intuition behind this theorem?

Comment: Just to clear up my own confusion — this is Mather’s *first* cube theorem, correct? It seems some authors say “Mather’s cube theorem” to reference the *second* cube theorem.

Comment: @SantanaAfton, yes this is the first cube theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what counts as an intuitive explanation, but this is sort of how I think about it.

Say that $B=B_1\cup B_2$ and $B_0=B_1\cap B_2$. This is the second pushout square.

Now let $E_1$ be a bundle over $B_1$ and let $E_2$ be a bundle over $B_2$, and suppose that the restriction to $B_0$ is the same for both bundles -- call it $E_0$. These are the two given pullback squares. Now let $E$ be the union of $E_1$ and $E_2$ along $E_0$. This is the other pushout square. $E$ should be a bundle over $B$ whose restriction to $B_1$ (resp. $B_2$) is the bundle $E_1$ (resp. $E_2$).

Comment: Dear Tom, in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/90044/69037) you write the theorem fails in the category of sets. Doesn't that mean the intuition of strictly pulling back bundles fails?

Comment: @Arrow The theorem holds in sets if one of the given pullback squares intersects the pushout squares in a pair of monomorphisms. In the homotopy theory of simplicial sets any map can be made a monomorphism, so in fact it is possible to deduce the cube theorem from its set version.

Comment: @Arrow, the theorem is about homotopy pushouts rather than pushouts, but I don't know how to give geometric intuition without switching to actual pushouts. And that means I should be looking at pushouts that are also homotopy pushouts, so at least one of the maps $B_0\to B_1$ and $B_0\to B_2$ should be some kind of nice injection.